# Error: Syntax error. Extra IF

Tags: formula, formula-field

If meeting_type__c= ‘FaceToface’ (picklist) and Time is before 21:00.
Set datetime on time__c at 17:00
Otherwise  21:00

If  meeting_type__c= ‘byCall’ (piclist) and time is before 14:30
Set datetime on time__c at 19:00

If  meeting_type__c= ‘byCall’ (piclist) and time is after 14:30 and before 17:00
Set datetime on time__c at 17:00
Otherwise 23:30

```
IF( 
  
 AND(
          ISPICKVAL(  meeting_type__c, 'FaceToFace'),Time__c < TIMEVALUE("21:00:00.00")
         ) 
 
   ,TIMEVALUE("17:00:00.00") , TIMEVALUE("21:00:00.00") 
 )



IF ( 
       AND(
             ISPICKVAL(  meeting_type__c, 'byCall'),Time__c < TIMEVALUE("14:30:00.00")
          ) 

 ,  TIMEVALUE("19:00:00.00") , 


IF( 
  
 AND(
          ISPICKVAL(  meeting_type__c, 'byCall'),Time__c > TIMEVALUE("14:30:00.00"), Time__c > TIMEVALUE("17:00:00.00")
         ) 
 
   ,TIMEVALUE("17:00:00.00") , TIMEVALUE("23:30:00.00") 
 )


)
```

Why do I get an extra IF error??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're 1st `IF` loop is not join into 2nd and 3rd `If`loops, So it's provide result of 2 `If` loops, That's why you get error as extra `if` loop.

Please combine your `if` loop as followingly,

```
Case ( TEXT(meeting_type__c),
        
        'FaceToFace', IF (Time__c < TIMEVALUE("21:00:00.00"), ,TIMEVALUE("17:00:00.00") , TIMEVALUE("21:00:00.00")),
        'byCall', IF (Time__c < TIMEVALUE("14:30:00.00"), TIMEVALUE("19:00:00.00") , IF((Time__c > TIMEVALUE("14:30:00.00") && Time__c < TIMEVALUE("17:00:00.00")), TIMEVALUE("17:00:00.00"), TIMEVALUE("23:30:00.00"))),
        
       TIMEVALUE("00:00:00.00") //Default
        
        )
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: it's working  thanks

Comment: how to add hour to DateTime field??  suppose DateTime field is  2/2/2021 9 :am    I want to show  2/2/201 2 : am ??how I add hour by  above condtion

Comment: Is this issue raised for diff. timezone? If yes, You don't need to added, Salesforce default convert the datetime values based on user timezone.